# setting background color of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in one activity effects another activity?

Tags: android

So I have 2 activities both with a support Toolbar. The toolbar is a different color on the 2 activities so I have defined a base color (white) in the toolbar xml and then in the other activity if override the background. For some reason if I switch between the 2 activities 5 or 6 times the background of the non default activity ends up becoming the background for the other activity.

Code time:

Layout of the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- We use a Toolbar so that our drawer can be displayed
 in front of the action bar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <!-- I have to use a custom view in order to set a custom font. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
`
```

Login Layout (with changing toolbar color)
    `

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar_seam"/>-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/login_gradient"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/company_program_label"
            style="@style/basicShadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/platform_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/company_program_label"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/username_input_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/login_field_top"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save_username"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save_username"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:hint="@string/login_username_hint"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />
                <!--android:background="#FFFFFF"-->

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/save_username"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/pin_up"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/password_input_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/username_input_wrapper"
                android:background="@drawable/login_field"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_password"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/show_password"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show_password"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/eye_closed"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                style="@style/basic_button_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/password_input_wrapper"
                android:background="@drawable/login_button"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/login_login_button"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/platform_wrapper"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/login_terms_and_policy"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forgot_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#66000000"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="@string/login_forgot_button"
            android:textColor="#66FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

other layout (which should have the default toolbar color)

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_seam"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/debug_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

In the login activity I have the following code to change the toolbar background color:

```
protected void themeToolbar()
{
        super.themeToolbar();
        this.navigationBack();
        this.titleBlank();
        this.toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

In order to transition between the activities I have a textview with a custom schema that triggers the other intent via LinkMovementMethod

```
terms = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.terms);
terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The first couple of times i transition to and from the other activity everything is fine but after about 6 times the entire background of the other activity changes to the color set in `this.toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` which is really weird because the toolbar doesn't cover the entire page. What is even worse is that views that used to be white on the login activity now show up red.

My best guess is that there is some kind of shared ColorDrawable using for all white backgrounds and that it is being overridden with the the red color but I have no idea why.

Login as it should be:
[image: Login as it should be]

Other activity as it should be:
[image: Other activity as it should be]

Other activity after switching back and forth 6 times:
[image: Other activity after switching back and forth 6 times]

Login activity after other activity screws up:

[image: Login activity after other activity screws up]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android shares the background drawable in activities with the same Theme. So create a new Drawable if you want to explicit set it:

`setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED))`

Answer (score 1):

Use different styles for the toolbar instead changing the background explicitly. The color of the toolbar will be per activity, you can use whatever color you want.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<!-- For transparent toolbar -->
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent" parent="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now just set the style of the toolbar.

Regular Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />
```

Transparent Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent" />
```